# md5sums differ between CIFS and NFS

Tags: linux, samba, nfs, md5

I'm doing some research on 'cribbage' an Ubuntu 10.04 box which connects to 'prodcsamba01' via CIFS:

```
cribbage $ mount | grep prep
//prodcsamba01/prepfsnr on /prep type cifs (rw,mand,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
```

prodcsamba01 in turn has '/prepfsnr' mounted from the server 'prepfsnr01'.

In the course of my research, I ran `file` on the file `0522_3600001.raw.gz`:

```
cribbage $ file /prep/ftphome/archive/raw/0522_3600001.raw.gz    /prep/ftphome/archive/raw/0522_3600001.raw.gz: gzip compressed data, was "0520_2460001.raw", from Unix, last modified: Sun May 20 08:16:53 2012
```

Note that the filename inside the zip file is supposedly `"0520_2460001.raw"`, even though the file name is `0522_3600001.raw.gz`.

At this point, I logged in to `ftpproc`, which has the directory that cribbage sees as `/prep` mounted as `/prepfsnr/prep`. The mount is via NFS.

I ran `file` on the same file, and I get different results:

```
ftpproc $ file /prepfsnr/prep/ftphome/archive/raw/0522_3600001.raw.gz
/prepfsnr/prep/ftphome/archive/raw/0522_3600001.raw.gz: gzip compressed data, was "0522_3600001.raw", from Unix, last modified: Tue May 22 09:18:51 2012     Tue May 22 11:23:50
```

`md5sum` is also different between CIFS and NFS:

```
ftpproc $ md5sum /prepfsnr/prep/ftphome/archive/raw/0522_3600001.raw.gz
a722fb54448a2fea752461c2edadbded  /prepfsnr/prep/ftphome/archive/raw/0522_3600001.raw.gz

cribbage $ md5sum /prep/ftphome/archive/raw/0522_3600001.raw.gz
a745dbf6c741d698839e4a9c2166f821  /prep/ftphome/archive/raw/0522_3600001.raw.gz
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons, CIFS allows clients to get exclusive access to a file, in which case they can locally make changes that are not immediately sent to the server.

Is there perhaps an application that still has an exclusive lock on this file? The smbstatus command (on the server) should be able to tell you.